# Get Windows Authentication Token Using Javascript to have Integrated Security (NOT using IIS)

Tags: javascript, security, authentication, integrated

I want to authenticate users on a web application. The users are already logged into their Windows Network.
Notice, this is NOT Internet Information Server. I have a Java Application Server on the other side.
Is there a way using Javascript or something, so that a Windows Authentication can be taken, then sent to the server, and on the server, that token being validated (assuming the server is on the same network).
I have found that you can [convert a token into a Windows Principal](http://alt.pluralsight.com/wiki/default.aspx/Keith.GuideBook/HowToCreateAWindowsPrincipalGivenAToken.html)
So I need the Client part. A way to send that token to the server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you setup your Java web application to support NTLM authentication, e.g. by using the HttpServletFilter from the Samba Java library, this should work without implementing any client side JavaScript.

Depending on which browser the client is using, you may however have to configure the browser to enable NTLM authentication against you server. If I'm not wrong, IE is by default configured to allow transparent NTLM authentication against servers on the local network, but in Firefox, you have to enable NTLM for each specific server address.

Comment: Imagine you cannot change the application to support NTLM. Do you think of an other way of doing it?
I'm actually wanting to see if there is some Javascript way to catch the Windows Token using Javascript. The fact is that our application allows us to create a SSO provider, that we have already created, in Microsoft C++ and we could convert that token into a Windows Principal, and then later decide if it is authenticated or not.